# Azure NSG - Filter certain IPs from input csv

Tags: azure, csv, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg

I am using PowerShell to create Azure NSGs which will use input from a .csv file with security rules. I am using the script below.

```
$NSG = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name test -ResourceGroupName RG-VM-QTY

foreach($rule in import-csv "SystemPath\inputfile.csv") 
{ 
$NSG | Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $rule.name -Access Allow -Protocol $rule.protocol -Direction $rule.direction -Priority $rule.priority 
-SourceAddressPrefix $rule.source -SourcePortRange * 
-DestinationAddressPrefix $rule.destination -DestinationPortRange $rule.port 
}

$NSG | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
```

Wanted to check if there is a way to restrict adding a particular IP lets say 127.0.0.1 to be added as source or destination in any of the rules.
Any check that I can put to avoid creating the NSG altogether if the IP 127.0.0.1 is present in the .csv?

Thanks in advance guys.!
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the modified PowerShell script with a simple **if condition** added to check that SourceAddressPrefix and DestinationAddressPrefix should not be exactly 127.0.0.1

```
$NSG = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name test -ResourceGroupName RG-VM-QTY 

foreach($rule in import-csv "SystemPath\inputfile.csv") 
{
   # additional if condition to check that source or destination address prefix should not be 127.0.0.1
   if($rule.SourceAddressPrefix -ne "127.0.0.1" -And $rule.DestinationAddressPrefix -ne "127.0.0.1")
   { 
          $NSG | Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $rule.name -Access Allow -Protocol $rule.protocol -Direction $rule.direction -Priority $rule.priority 
             -SourceAddressPrefix $rule.source -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix $rule.destination -DestinationPortRange $rule.port 
   }
} 

$NSG | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
```

Your condition right now is very simple to check for 127.0.0.1 so if condition should be good enough.

In case you get to a more complicated logic, consider creating a separate function say something like ValidateRule(), that can encapsulate all conditions and call that function to check whether or not the rule should be added.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there a way to put exception handler to throw error when it reads the IP 127.0.0.1 in source or destination?